# Aguna solucion con angular y apirest!

Tags: javascript

Ayuda gente!!! me tira este error : **org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageE…nTranslationInterceptor.java:137)\r\n\t... 69 more\r\n'** intente todo, cuando lo pruebo en postman me deja ingresar datos asi, ya intente todo y nada. Porfavor alguna solucion.. seguramente ustedes van a poder responderme la duda..

`{"name":"tarea1,"taskFolder":[{"folderName":"Algo"}]}`

**Task service front**

```
      import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
      import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
      import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    
       @Injectable({
       providedIn: 'root'
       })
       export class TaskService {
    
      private url = "http://localhost:8080/task";
    
      constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
    
       public getAllTasks(): Observable<any>{
       return this.http.get(this.url + '/listTask');
    
       }
    
       public addTask(task:any):Observable<any>{
      return this.http.post(this.url + '/saveTask',task);
       } 
    
       }
    
       import { Component } from '@angular/core';
       import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
        import { TaskService } from './services/task/task.service';
        import { FolderService } from './services/Folder/folder.service';
        
        @Component({
          selector: 'app-root',
          templateUrl: './app.component.html',
          styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
        })
        export class AppComponent {
        
        taskForm:FormGroup;
        folder:any;
        
          constructor(
            public fb:FormBuilder,
            public taskService : TaskService,
            public folderService: FolderService
          ){
        
          }
        
          ngOnInit():void{
            this.taskForm = this.fb.group({
              name :['', Validators.required],
              taskFolder:['',Validators.required]
            });{
              
          this.folderService.getAllFolder().subscribe(resp => {this.folder = 
       resp},
            error=>(console.error(error)));
            
          }
        }
          
        saveTask():void{
         
          this.taskService.addTask(this.taskForm.value).subscribe(
            resp=>{console.log(resp)},
            error =>{(console.error(error))}
          )
        }
        
        
        }
```

**Clase task**

```
        @Entity
        @Table(name="tasks")
        public class Task {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private long idTask;
        
        @Basic
        public String name;
    
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name = "fk_folder")
        @JsonBackReference  
        private Folder taskFolder;
    
        public Task() {
            super();
        }
    
        public Task(long idTask, String name, Folder taskFolder) {
            super();
            this.idTask = idTask;
            this.name = name;
            this.taskFolder = taskFolder;
        }
    
        public long getIdTask() {
            return idTask;
        }
    
        public void setIdTask(long idTask) {
            this.idTask = idTask;
        }
    
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    
        public Folder gettaskFolder() {
            return taskFolder;
        }
    
        public void settaskFolder(Folder taskFolder) {
            this.taskFolder = taskFolder;
        }   
    }
```

**Clase folder**

```
       @Entity
       @Table(name="folders")
       public class Folder {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private long idFolder;
        
        @Basic
        private String folderName;
        
        @OneToMany(mappedBy="taskFolder", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JsonManagedReference
        
        private List<Task> tasksFold;
    
        public Folder() {
            super();
        }
    
        public Folder(long idFolder, String folderName, List<Task> tasksFold) 
       {
            super();
            this.idFolder = idFolder;
            this.folderName = folderName;
            this.tasksFold = tasksFold;
        }
    
        public long getIdFolder() {
            return idFolder;
        }
    
        public void setIdFolder(long idFolder) {
            this.idFolder = idFolder;
        }
    
        public String getFolderName() {
            return folderName;
        }
    
        public void setFolderName(String folderName) {
            this.folderName = folderName;
        }
    
        public List<Task> getTasksFold() {
            return tasksFold;
        }
    
        public void setTasksFold(List<Task> tasksFold) {
            this.tasksFold = tasksFold;
        }
    }
```

**Task Controller**

```
        @RestController
        @RequestMapping(value = "task")
        @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200") 
        public class TaskController {
    
        @Autowired
        private ITaskService taskRep;
        
        //Get all tasks.
        @GetMapping("/listTask")
        @ResponseBody
        public  List<Task> findTasks(){
            List<Task> listTask = taskRep.listTasks();
            return listTask;
            }
        
        //Save a task
        @PostMapping("/saveTask")
        @ResponseBody
        public Task saveTask(@RequestBody Task task) {
            taskRep.save(task);
            return task;
        }
        
        //Delete a task
        @GetMapping("/delete/{id}")
        public ResponseEntity<Task> deleteTask (@PathVariable(value = "id") 
        long idTask) {
            Task task = taskRep.listarId(idTask);
            if(task != null) {
                taskRep.delete(task);
                return new ResponseEntity<Task> (task, HttpStatus.OK);
            }else {
                return new ResponseEntity<Task> (task, 
        HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            }
            
        }
        
        //Update task.
        @GetMapping("/update/{id}")
        public ResponseEntity<Task> updateTask (@PathVariable(value="id")         
        long idTask){
            Task task = taskRep.listarId(idTask);
            if(task!=null) {
                String name = task.getName();
                task.setName(name);
                taskRep.save(task);
                return new ResponseEntity<Task> (task, HttpStatus.OK);
            }else {
                return new ResponseEntity<Task> (task, 
        HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    
            }
        }
        
    }
```

cuando lo pude hacer andar, lo unico que logro es que me ponga null donde iria el id de la carpeta, tampoco al listar me muestra las carpetas, solo el nombre y ID de las tareas correspondientes, dejo el codigo de backend y frontend para que se pueda ver, estoy trabajando con apirest springbootjava y angular.. gracias si se necesita alguna parte mas del codigo porfavor diganme, soy inexperto... Gracias..

Comment: Te da un error en back y nos enseñas el código de front... maravilloso. Por favor, añade **TODO** el código relacionado con el problema, y el stacktrace ***ENTERO***, no solo un trozo cortado. Es muy complicado intentar depurar un error ajeno si ni siquiera podemos ver el código! Nosotros no estamos sentados delante de tu código, intenta darnos todas las piezas necesarias para poder entender qué pasa! Por el trozo que veo tienes una `InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException` eso significa que has intentado guardar algo que no encaja con tu modelo, o que no está correctamente creado.

Comment: Hola amigo, mil disculpas.. Soy nuevo y no me dejaba cargar el codigo, ahora intento modificarlo

Comment: puede ser de utilidad https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/support/PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.html

Comment: Class InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException-->Excepción lanzada por el uso incorrecto de la API, como no "compilar" un objeto de consulta que necesitaba compilación antes de la ejecución. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException.html